# Sum cell not auto updating

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have cells populated across a few columns and rows. Two columns I have a sum total at the end. When I insert a new row directly above the totals, and populate a new row of data, one of the sum totals auto updates but the other one doesn't, so I have to highlight the area it is summing and drag down one more cell. The one that does auto update is summing static data ie I just type it in. The total that doesn't auto update is summing cells which have equations in them. I just drag the equation from above. If in the newly inserted row I add a static value into the column with the equations, the total doesn't auto update. However if I insert a row in the middle of the table, both totals will automatically update, whether I populate the relevant cells with equation or static data. I don't want to do this though. I want to insert the new row directly above the totals row. Can help please?

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it easier to read (split paragraphs) will increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the range into a table.

Highlight the area and in the 'insert' ribbon select table. Now functions will automatically populate in new rows and columns.